# How to implement the equivalent of the Aggregator EIP in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm very experienced with Apache Camel and EIPs and am struggling to understand how to implement equivalents in Nifi. I understand that Nifi uses a different paradigm (flow based programming) but I don't think what I'm trying to do is unreasonable.

In a nutshell I want the contents of each file to be sent to many rest services and I want to aggregate the responses into a single document which will stored in elasticsearch. I might also do some further processing and cleanup to improve what is stored (but this isn't my immediate issue)

The screenshot is a quick mock-up of what I'm trying to achieve but I don't understand enough about Nifi to know how to implement this pattern correctly.

[image: Nfii Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to take a single piece of data and then fork to multiple parts of the flow and then converge back, there needs to be a way for MergeContent to know which pieces go together.

There are generally two ways this can be done...

The first is using MergeContent in "defragment mode". Think of this as reversing a split operation that was performed by one of the split processors like SplitText. For example, you split a file of 100 lines into 100 flow files of 1 line each, then do some stuff to each one, then want to converge back. The split processors produce a standard set of split attributes (described in the docs of the processors) and the defragment mode knows how to bin the splits accordingly and merge them back together. This probably doesn't apply to your example since you didn't start with a split processor.

The second approach is the "Correlation Attribute" in MergeConent. This tells merge content to only merge flow files together that have the same value for the attribute specified. In your example, when a file gets picked up by GetFile and sent to 3 InvokeHttp processors, there are 3 flow files created, and they all should have their "filename" attribute set to the name of the file picked up from disk. So telling MergeContent to correlate on filename should do the trick, and probably setting the min and max number of entries to the number you expect like 3, and a maximum time in case one of them fails or hangs.

Comment: Thanks, I saw those options in the docs in the end. Just need to prototype it up. Thanks